# Is there a way to convert an ePub page flip direction to rtl automatically?

Tags: formatting

In other words, can you update the spine tag with a script instead of converting to zip, opening, and replacing?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Create an epub3 book or convert your existing epub2 book to an epub3 book and add a `page-progression-direction="rtl"` attribute to the `<spine>` tag in the `content.opf` file.

You can convert epub2 books to epub3 books with [Calibre](https://calibre-ebook.com/download). (Polish books ▶ Upgrade book internals.)